# Uma box com msg antes de abrir o site

Tags: php, html, css

Bom estava querendo saber como começar a fazer isso que aparece na img
se tiver como alguém disponibilizar um code base ou algo q me ajude a fazer isso ficarei mt grato.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você quer uma tela dessa para confirmação?

Comment: sim, antes de carregar todo o site queria botar uma tela dessas

Comment: @GabrielCosta te recomendo a fazer o [tour] para entender como funciona a **comunidade**, primeiramente tente fazer algo, depois faça a pergunta expondo sua dúvida e ou problema.

Comment: Opa mano onde eu errei?

Comment: Eu já fiz umas perguntas até agora ninguém me falou isso, mas você me falando eu posso arrumar .

Comment: Tem vários plugins javascript que faz isso. Vou deixar dois exemplo utilizando jquery e criando o próprio layout de alerta. Exemplo 1: https://codepen.io/valdeir2000/pen/RxoYoj?editors=0010 Exemplo 2 (Plugin [SweetAlert](https://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/)): https://codepen.io/valdeir2000/pen/YYpOVr?editors=0010#0 Você também pode utilizar o modal do [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/), [jQuery Modal](http://jquerymodal.com/), dentre outros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode criar esses *box* de aviso com 2 `divs`: uma que será o fundo escuro transparente que ocupará toda a tela e outra que será o `box` com o aviso, centralizado horizontalmente e verticalmente com `display: flex`.

Criei também uma função que irá fechar o *box*, que pode ser via JavaScript puro ou jQuery (tudo isso é adaptável da forma que quiser).

Veja um exemplo que você poderá adaptar conforme a sua necessidade:

```js
function fechaAviso(){
   document.querySelector("#tela").style.display = "none";
   // jquery abaixo
   //$("#tela").hide();
}
```

```css
#tela {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    z-index: 999;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

#aviso{
   width: 300px;
   padding: 20px;
   background-color: #fff;
   border-radius: 10px;
   z-index: 999;
   top: 50%;
   align-self: center;
}

#aviso h2{
   margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<p>Texto texto Texto texto Texto texto Texto texto Texto texto Texto texto</p>
<div id="tela">
   <div id="aviso">
      <h2>BOX DE AVISO</h2>
      <p>Texto texto Texto texto Texto texto Texto texto Texto texto Texto texto</p>
      <input type="button" value="Fechar" onclick="fechaAviso()" />
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: muito obrigado mano vou testar aqui agora, eu tinha conseguido fazer um, mas ele não aparece no googlechrome só em outros navegadores, ah e mais uma coisa você tem interesse em fazer uma script php para mim? Estou procurando alguém para q eu possa pagar, se isso não for permitido aqui desculpe.

Comment: https://elojobmax.com.br/elojob ou  algo igual a esse https://elojobbrasil.com.br/#loja. Eu queria mt aprender php até pq curto bastentee, mas estou precisando deixar o site pronto até o dia 02, eu queria esse sistema onde vc escolhe : o Elo atual e o elo que vc quer o modo da fila e aparece o valor.

Comment: opa ok mano vou te chamar.

Comment: Pronto mano já te mandei um email, não sei como usa o gtalk kk.